# Android Checkbox preference

Tags: android, preference

I cannot find any tutorials on checkbox preference. I can use a listpreference, but I can't use checkbox preference. For now, I want that if user sets on the checbox, a toast msg says "true" and if he sets it off, the toast msg says "false". So far I have this:

preferences.xml:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference
          android:title="Show Call UI"
          android:defaultValue="true"
          android:summary="Show Call Interface when clicking call button"
          android:key="checkboxPref" />
```

EditPreferences.java:

```
public class EditPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    String listPreference;
    boolean checkboxPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        getPrefs();
    }

    private void getPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        listPreference = prefs.getString("listPref", "nr1");
        checkboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
    }
}
```

**Edit: Solution thanks to David Caunt:**

```
checkboxPreference.
    setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (newValue.toString().equals("true")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CB: " + "true",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CB: " + "false",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please edit this to have variables begin with small letters - it is _very_ confusing to see things like `CheckboxPreference` as variable names !

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to add a listener to the Preference in your onCreate method

```
    final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("checkboxPref");

    checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Pref " + preference.getKey() + " changed to " + newValue.toString());       
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Small prob: "The method checkboxPref(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener(){}) is undefined for the type EditPreference"

Comment: Whoops! I accidentally deleted the method name - see revised answer above.

Comment: Great, nice touch adding the full solution to your question!

Answer (score 15):

You can cast the value of the checkbox into a boolean. This might be safer and more extensible than checking the toString() value.

```
final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("checkboxPref");

checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if(newValue instanceof Boolean){
            Boolean boolVal = (Boolean)newValue;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Log.i("LOG", String.valueOf(sp.getBoolean("key", false)));
```

Simplest way i found of getting value if item is pressed. If log is:

> I/LOG: true

Checkbox is pressed

> I/LOG: false

Checkbox is not selected

Hope this answers your question.